# cv2.imshow fail : Fontconfig error: failed reading config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, opencv

while runnning the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

im having an error  :

Fontconfig error: failed reading config file

(python:5882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Comment: The frame box came a large number, and hang the system not showing any video

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: Now, this is not an excellent solution, but I've solved it by downgrading my version, so simply by running:

`pip uninstall opencv-python`

`pip install -Iv opencv-python==4.2.0.34`

I've been also having the same problem ever since I've moved to *OpenCV 4.3.0.36*. I use Ubuntu 16.04, and could narrow the problem down until the *libfontconfig-42c558d2.so.1.11.1* library under *opencv_python.libs* directory.

Gotta mention, I use virtual environment by the way. In my opinion, this problem is due to a clash between the operating system's *libfontconfig* and OpenCV's own version because there is a statement in the licence file reading as follows.

> libfontconfig is redistributed within all opencv-python Linux and macOS packages.

...and I haven't had any problem like that in the previous versions.

You can see the full list of CV versions [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history) if that works for you. Hope this by-pass helps, especially if you have a deadline or something.

Comment: Yes, its works on Ubuntu 18.04 with opencv-python==4.2.0.34
But if ubuntu 20.04 work with opencv-python==4.3.0.36
Thanks a lot @merve

Answer (score -1):

try to edit the cv2 import because sometimes it have errors try `from cv2 import cv2` may works

Comment: I used the same command with from cv2 import cv2 and it works let me know it it didn't for you.